# Uniswap V3 Vyper contract reverting on "swap_usdc" function call

Tags: uniswap, vyper

I'm trying to create a simple Vyper contract that withdraws my `USDC` and converts this to a token that's passed through the argument list in the `swap_usdc` method.

I approve this contract to withdraw my `USDC` however, when attempting to call the `swap_usdc` method, the contract reverts.

I have no clue as to why and running out of ideas. Could it be that I'm not calling the UniswapV3 interfaces correctly?  Any other ideas/help much appreciated.

Here are my

**Input parameters:** `5000000` (5 USDC)

**Outtoken address:** `0x8505b9d2254A7Ae468c0E9dd10Ccea3A837aef5c` (Compound on Polygon)

**Failed tx hash:** `0x33db3c307813a307fd9086b41d3e3a92a5d601ba0a5c5b7c679cf32dbe9e2584`

**Code:**

```js
from vyper.interfaces import ERC20

USDC: constant(address) = 0x2791Bca1f2de4661ED88A30C99A7a9449Aa84174

UNIV3_ROUTER: constant(address) = 0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564


struct ExactInputSingleParams:  # ISwapRouter
    tokenIn: address
    tokenOut: address
    fee: uint256
    recipient: address
    deadline: uint256
    amountIn: uint256
    amountOutMinimum: uint256
    sqrtPriceLimitX96: uint256

struct ExactOutputSingleParams:  # ISwapRouter
    tokenIn: address
    tokenOut: address
    fee: uint256
    recipient: address
    deadline: uint256
    amountOut: uint256
    amountInMaximum: uint256
    sqrtPriceLimitX96: uint256

interface ISwapRouter:
    # @uniswap-v3-periphery/SwapRouter.sol
    def exactInputSingle(params: ExactInputSingleParams) -> uint256: payable
    def exactOutputSingle(params: ExactOutputSingleParams) -> uint256: payable
    def refundETH(): nonpayable


@external
def swap_usdc(amount_in: uint256, outtoken: address, desination: address):
    ERC20(USDC).transferFrom(msg.sender,self,amount_in)
    result: uint256 = ISwapRouter(UNIV3_ROUTER).exactInputSingle(
        ExactInputSingleParams({
            tokenIn: USDC,
            tokenOut: outtoken,
            fee: convert(3000, uint256),
            recipient: desination,
            deadline: block.timestamp,
            amountIn: amount_in,
            amountOutMinimum: 0,
            sqrtPriceLimitX96: empty(uint256)
        })
    )
```

Even when I update code to below based on feedback from people below, i still get wrong keccak value

```
from vyper.interfaces import ERC20



UNISWAP: constant(address) = 0x93bcDc45f7e62f89a8e901DC4A0E2c6C427D9F25 #0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D ethereum


@external
def swap(_from: address, _to: address, _amount: uint256, _minout: uint256) -> Bytes[32]:
        ERC20(_from).transferFrom(msg.sender,self,_amount)
        ERC20(_from).approve(UNISWAP, _amount)
        
        result: Bytes[32] = raw_call(
        UNISWAP,
     concat(method_id("exactInputSingle((address,address,uint24,address,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint160))"),
        convert(_from, bytes32),
        convert(_to, bytes32),
        convert(3000, bytes32),
        convert(msg.sender, bytes32),
        convert(block.timestamp, bytes32),
        convert(_amount, bytes32),
        convert(_minout, bytes32),
        convert(0, bytes32)
        ),
        is_delegate_call=False,
        max_outsize=32
        )

        assert convert(result,uint256) >= _minout, "less"
        return result
```

Comment: Can you add the input parameters you are using as well as the exact error message that you get returned in your question?

Comment: Have you called the `approve` function on the USDC token contract to allow your contract to spend the tokens?

Comment: You should add parameters, and either a failed transaction hash, or the failing calldata for simulation.

Comment: @RohanNero input parameters: amount_in 5000000 (5 USDC), outtoken address: 0x8505b9d2254A7Ae468c0E9dd10Ccea3A837aef5c (Compound on Polygon) destination my wallet address. I am compiling this and testing it in Remix in my browser, I simply get a contract revert error - I have approved the contract to withdraw my USDC (uint256 max).

Comment: @Maka failed tx hash: 0x33db3c307813a307fd9086b41d3e3a92a5d601ba0a5c5b7c679cf32dbe9e2584 pls see comment to RohanNero regarding tx params.

Comment: Tenderly debug link: https://dashboard.tenderly.co/shared/simulation/6f076247-3405-4717-8d75-cb107498a904

Comment: You changed the router address across the two examples, look at them both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim is failing with:

> "Error Message: Called function does not exist in the contract"

Looks like you are creating an incorrect call signature.

It should be `0x414bf389` the keccak of:

```
exactInputSingle((address,address,uint24,address,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint160))
```

You are calling `0x53640a38`
the keccak of:

```
exactInputSingle((address,address,uint256,address,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint256))
```

Fix the interface and try encoding the specific uint sizes `convert(_literal, uint24)` etc.

#### edit:

One way to handle this (as well as almost any other situation) is to raw_call:

```py
interface IERC20:
  def approve(spender: address, amount: uint256) -> bool: nonpayable
  def transferFrom(sender: address, recipient: address, amount: uint256) -> bool: nonpayable

USDC: constant(address) = 0x2791Bca1f2de4661ED88A30C99A7a9449Aa84174
UNIV3_ROUTER: constant(address) = 0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564

@external
def swap_usdc(amount_in: uint256, outtoken: address, destination: address, fee: uint256):
  IERC20(USDC).transferFrom(msg.sender, self, amount_in)
  IERC20(USDC).approve(UNIV3_ROUTER, amount_in)

  raw_call(
    UNIV3_ROUTER,
    concat(
      method_id("exactInputSingle((address,address,uint24,address,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint160))"),
      convert(USDC, bytes32),
      convert(outtoken, bytes32),
      convert(fee, bytes32),
      convert(destination, bytes32),
      convert(block.timestamp, bytes32),
      convert(amount_in, bytes32),
      convert(0, bytes32),
      convert(0, bytes32)
    ),
    is_delegate_call=False,
  )
```

#### edit addressing updated issue:

The code above works. The issue you are having now is a result of changing the router address from the one in your first example. Using the v2 router won't work as it doesn't have the same functions.

Simply replace the contract address you have under UNISWAP with the one you used under UNIV3_ROUTER above that.

If you use the code exactly as in my example it works, I have also validated an example which is the same outside of not explicitly setting False for delegate call, but it is the default so effectively identical.

Validated contract example: https://polygonscan.com/address/0x870a986c7685494db8759a612368494a9be51fbe#code

Play with it if still having issues.

---

#### edit to respond to request in comment:

> how does the contract change if we want to deposit native tokens to it?

The pools don't support eth, where eth is used it has to be wrapped first.
With v3 there is a statement in the `pay` function which is called during the swap:

```js
if (token == WETH9 && address(this).balance >= value)
  // pay with WETH9
  IWETH9(WETH9).deposit{value: value}(); // wrap only what is needed to pay
  IWETH9(WETH9).transfer(recipient, value);
```

Make the function payable, send the value on with the call, and use the 'weth' (wrapped native) token address.

```py
interface IERC20:
  def approve(spender: address, amount: uint256) -> bool: nonpayable
  def transferFrom(sender: address, recipient: address, amount: uint256) -> bool: nonpayable

WETH: constant(address) = 0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270
UNIV3_ROUTER: constant(address) = 0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564

# add payable
@payable
@external
def swap_eth(amount_in: uint256, outtoken: address, destination: address, fee: uint256):
  assert msg.value >= amount_in, 'Not enough eth supplied.' # remember to send an amount of the native coin

  raw_call(
    UNIV3_ROUTER,
    concat(
      method_id("exactInputSingle((address,address,uint24,address,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint160))"),
      convert(WETH, bytes32),
      convert(outtoken, bytes32),
      convert(fee, bytes32),
      convert(destination, bytes32),
      convert(block.timestamp, bytes32),
      convert(amount_in, bytes32),
      convert(0, bytes32),
      convert(0, bytes32)
    ),
    value=msg.value  # pass native to the router
  )
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, vyper doesnt seem to support uint24, uint160 so I've cast them as uint256- what can I do to make it work? Grateful for your help

Comment: See updated answer with example.

Comment: I'm still struggling.. still getting wrong keccak value despite using code above.. @maka https://dashboard.tenderly.co/shared/simulation/bd540d49-bd95-4179-b4e4-b13f7522fd82

Comment: The code should have worked as was, double check what you have that isn't the same. Seems you are calling the wrong router, v2 which doesn't have that function. Call v3router.

Comment: Grateful as always @maka I’m using the same address for Uniswap as before - how can I call v3?

Comment: Much love. But you can't be using the same one. One above is 0xE592427A0AEce92De3Edee1F18E0157C05861564, you are calling: 0x93bcDc45f7e62f89a8e901DC4A0E2c6C427D9F25 which is the v2 router.. Maybe try find and replace in your code.

Comment: That was the issue! thank you - how does the contract change if we want to deposit native tokens to it? I've made the method payable, I've put from token as 0xeeeeee , removed the transferfrom and approve, but doesnt seem to work

Comment: Need to use weth, pools don't support eth. If eth is used it has to be wrapped first. For v3 there is a line... "(token == WETH9 && address(this).balance >= value)". Make the function payable, send the value on with the call, and use the 'weth' (wrapped native) token address. To unwrap you would do two calls in one with a different function called mullticall, encode a swap then a unwrapWeth and then encode them both as a multicall byte array.

Comment: Added an example, but it is barely related to question title at this point, I think anything else would need a new question.