# getAmountsOut and sushiswap user interface shows different result

Tags: uniswap, ethereum-wallet-dapp, cpp-ethereum, sushiswap

Hello eth communities..

I am trying to interact with ethereum chain using programming and I'm using getAmountsOut to get swap path quote using sushiswap's contract. But the result in my vscode and sushiswap UI is veryyyy different even the path sushiswap UI(user interface) used is the same with mine(using only v2). See this senario

```
in my code the path WETH -> DPI gives me 8.988475884524729051 DPI

on sushiswap UI the path WETH- DPI gives me 9.26355

The path i used is only sushiswapv2

the path sushiswap UI used is sushiswapV2
```

Please help..... Even i deduct the gas from sushiswap UI resut, still the results are not even closer.... Also does getAmountsOut consider the gas cost?

Comment: getAmountsOut should return the same as UI, can find examples of that from me in their discord. UI adds some padding to slippage but getAmount(s)Out can line line up 100%. So you should share more details of how you are getting to the result. Should also check your result on app.sushi.com instead of www.sushi.com to avoid some difference from tines.

Comment: with app.sushiswap the result is exactly the same. Can u please tell me why it is not same with www.sushiswap ? and does getAmountsOut consider the gas cost?

Comment: No it doesn't consider gas cost, just 0.3% swapfee. It's hard to say without seeing how you get to that result, why it is different. Maybe not every input is what you think it is. I would copy the getAmountOut function and call getReserves() on the pools in the path and step through it manually, to find out what is going on.

Comment: This is the different i get..see the screenshot... the right one is app.sushiswap and the left one is www.sushiswap... my result is the same with the right one

https://snipboard.io/zgXAxJ.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it, the prices *are* different across the two urls, app.sushi.com shows the same as getAmountOut with 2+% price impact.

[www.sushi.com](http://www.sushi.com) shows more as it is aggregating from multiple pools to give you the best price. If anything it is just an inaccuracy in what it is showing as the path on the newer UI.

[image]

#### edit:

> Hello brother is there a way i can calculate the amount i get after swap using resrve0 and reserve1. Example The pool MKR/WETH have WETH reserve of 137562296675513055507 and MKR reserve of 95089610234884719383 If i input 1 ETH How to calculate the amount of MKR i get??

On the simplest level you can call getAmountOut, or copy the way the function does it from the Uniswap library.

```
    function getAmountOut(uint amountIn, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) internal pure returns (uint amountOut) {
        require(amountIn > 0, 'UniswapV2Library: INSUFFICIENT_INPUT_AMOUNT');
        require(reserveIn > 0 && reserveOut > 0, 'UniswapV2Library: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY');
        uint amountInWithFee = amountIn.mul(997);
        uint numerator = amountInWithFee.mul(reserveOut);
        uint denominator = reserveIn.mul(1000).add(amountInWithFee);
        amountOut = numerator / denominator;
    }
```

An example implementation might look like:

```py
>>> def getAmountOut(amountIn: int, reserveIn: int, reserveOut: int) -> int:
...   amountInWithFee = amountIn * 997
...   numerator = amountInWithFee * reserveOut
...   denominator = (reserveIn * 1000) + amountInWithFee
...   amountOut = numerator // denominator
...   return int(amountOut)
...
>>> getAmountOut(1*10**18,95089610234884719383,137562296675513055507)
1427354024147827329
>>> getAmountOut(1*10**18,137562296675513055507,95089610234884719383)/10**18
0.6842149439181904
>>> getAmountOut(1*10**18,95089610234884719383,137562296675513055507)/10**18
1.4273540241478273
>>>
```

Have included the reserves in reverse of suggested as I think you got them back to front in the question.

The last result suggests 1.4273540241478273MKR for 1 ETH which is close to the current market rate.

Comment: so to get best rate like suhiswap UI, i must use reserve0 and reserve1 and calcuate the quote right? or is thier other way to tell getAmountsOut to use specific pool? I see that there is 2 pools in sushiswap. The one is https://www.sushi.com/pool/1%3A0x34b13f8cd184f55d0bd4dd1fe6c07d46f245c7ed , which gives 9.22DPI and the other one is https://www.sushi.com/pool/137%3A0xcb3716006b3b468624b2a246505ec0d22673e077 which gives 8.76DPI for same input 0.35 ETH

Comment: One is on Polygon the other Ethereum they won't be the same. v2 can only have 1 pool for each pair, in order to get the price from the newer UI you would use the route processor and pull different amounts from different pool routes by setting the share field in each route. Sushiswap has a system called tines for this, to do yourself you would need a good understanding of v2 and then additional understanding of the other pool types on the platform. With that you would parse data for all relevant pools to calculate the optimal fractions.

Comment: ok ... Thanks very much Maka. U really helped me a lot...

Comment: Much love and good luck on your journey

Comment: Hello brother is there a way i can calculate the amount i get after swap using resrve0 and reserve1. Example The pool MKR/WETH have 

WETH reserve of  137562296675513055507 and
MKR reserve of 95089610234884719383

If i input 1 ETH How to calculate the amount of MKR i get??

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: using getAmountOut is better choice.... one last question does those uniswap and sushiswap UI output amounts include gas cost. Right?

Comment: No it doesn't include gas, set that in your wallet or transaction parameters.

Comment: and When i try to access uniswapv3 like uniswapv2, i can't. because the ABI is different and all the functions i use in uniswapV2 are not avaliable on UniswapV3 contract. What shall i do to access uniswapV3 using JSON-RPC like UniswapV2? I use C++ and for my node provider infura and blastAPI...

Comment: They are different contracts with different factory and pool contracts. You can't use the same calls. v3 has a quoter contract you can call for prices. Read the lower part of my answer here and follow links to guides on the v3quoter: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/154222/raw-call-to-uniswap-quoter-contract-fails-raw-call-did-not-return-a-value/154227#154227

Comment: u right. I understand that they are different. this is the ABI link. i can only call this functions using JSON-RPC

https://etherscan.io/address/0xe592427a0aece92de3edee1f18e0157c05861564#code

See the ABI

Comment: do u mean this contract?
https://etherscan.io/address/0x1f98431c8ad98523631ae4a59f267346ea31f984#code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148449/discussion-between-maka-and-biruk-damte).

Comment: OK....tnx..... to swap i i think this is the right ABI right? https://etherscan.io/address/0xe592427a0aece92de3edee1f18e0157c05861564#code

and also i see, uniswapv3 quoter,factory and router doesn't have getPair, getReserve and similar functionalities. Where i can get them in uniswapv3? did they depriciated?